# Azure mobile service using aad "The 'Bearer' HTTP authentication scheme is not supported" error

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile service setup and have followed the examples online for authenticating.  I call AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken and get back a token. Then I set the header using:

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AquireAccessToken());

However I am getting a 401 back and in the Azure logs I am getting "The 'Bearer' HTTP authentication scheme is not supported". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a service to call the mobile service why not use the Application key instead of a login process?

You can set a header on your request like so:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "<YOUR APP KEY>";
```

You can get your application key from the portal. When you are on the dashboard view click the button at the bottom of the window to "manage keys".

This works if you want to login as the service, but if you need to login on behalf of a user, then you'll need to go the authentication route. You'll also need to make sure the permissions on your various tables and APIs allow the application key level of access.

Alternately, you can use the *X-ZUMO-MASTER* header with your master key to get admin rights to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Services does not support tokens being passed in the Authorization header. Instead, please consider using the [POST method for the login endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx). The Mobile Services SDK makes this available as an overload of the login method if desired.

Could you please comment on what examples you are following? Our standard ["Get Started with Authentication" tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/) shows how to do login without handling an access token directly. We also have tutorials for using a provider SDK to obtain a token and pass it to the mobile service using the overloads mentioned above. For example, we have this tutorial for [Microsoft Account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-single-sign-on/) and [Azure Active Directory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-adal-sso-authentication/)

Comment: The mobile service will be called from a few different applications but the first one I am working on is a service. I was using the examples from the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx#BKMK_Daemon). Are there any code samples for an unattended service? I get the login portion but then how do I pass the authenticationToken on authenticated requests? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Once you have a Mobile Services token as a result of the method I mentioned before, you would pass it in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header when making calls to the service.