# Azure Mobile Services, Auth0, Web Api & Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, azure-mobile-services, bearer-token

For a mobile application (Cordova & AngularJS), I use Azure Mobile Services with Web Api.
I am currently experimenting with different OAuth implementations to see which one fits my needs the most.
Tried OAuth from ngCordova, OAuth.io, WAMS server flow and Auth0 with WAMS delegation.
I also came across the option using the "JsonWebToken DelegationHandler for WebAPI". With this approach, I should use the "System.Web.Http.Authorize" attribute. When I debug the `JsonWebTokenValidationHandler`, everything looks good (IsAuthenticated is true etc.), but at the end, a 401 is being returned.
I guess, WAMS overwrites the user principal. A look at the WAMS log reveals that "The 'Bearer' HTTP authentication scheme is not supported." As soon as there is such an authentication token present it seems to get rejected by Azure Mobile Services.

My first thought was, that I can probably remove a specific message handler but that doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone have an idea to get this to work with WAMS?

Answer (score 0):

There is another post with a question very similar to this one:
[Azure mobile service using aad "The 'Bearer' HTTP authentication scheme is not supported" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967223/azure-mobile-service-using-aad-the-bearer-http-authentication-scheme-is-not-s)

You can pass the application key in the header like so:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "<YOUR APP KEY>";
```

In that link, Matthew mentions details about how to user authentication and posts links on how to set it up properly which you may find valuable.

Comment: I'm already passing the client key using this header, but I was trying to use the ´Authorize´ attribute over the ´AuthorizeLevel´ to be more flexible in environment regards (to be able to run the backend not only on azure mobile services but also on azure websites).